# Call calendar function with JQuery and MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am doing a project, where I want to return the column `"All_hours"` from MySQL database. My question is regarding a calendar system.

I am trying to implement a calendar system, where I can choose a "from" date "to" date. It looks like **[this](http://postimg.org/image/5y2r26pe1/)**

The connection to my database is through a servlet which is named dataExchange.java. The calendar is programmed in JQuery. So the point is that the time period I choose from the calendar, fx: `2014-01-01` to `2014-03-03` shall return All_hours in that period from the MySQL database.

I have started to make some code, but I don't know if I am on the right track?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Working Hours</title>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/checkUser.js"> </script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    });

     $.get( "dataExchange.java", {startDate: $("#datepicker").val()},
             function( data ) {
                    $( ".result" ).html( data );
                        alert( "Load was performed." );

        });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
    <input id="datepicker"/>
    <input id="datepicker2" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help me on the way?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datepicker you can pass in a bunch of different data to customize it on an as needed basis.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ has some information on it.

I limit the dates for the datpicker by doing something like:

```
var custom_days_off = ["2-10-2012","3-10-2012","28-9-2012"];
$("input#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
      var noweekends = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
      if(noweekends[0]){
          var dmy = date.getDate()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getFullYear();
          if ($.inArray(dmy, custom_days_off )<0){ 
             return [true,"","Book Now!"]; 
          }else{
             return [false,"","No Slots"];
          }
      }else{ return noweekends;}
  }
});
```

in this example:  you can use your mySql to build `custom_days_off`, etc